# how to perform a mongoose query by Id and filter with a property in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this method to query an object by id.

```
getRoom: function(req, res) {
     var roomId = req.params.roomId;
     var availability = true;
     var language = 'english';
     Room.findById(roomId).exec((err, room) => {
        
         if (err || !room) {
             return res.status(404).send({
                 status: 'error',
                 message: 'No existe la habitacion'
             });
         }

         return res.status(200).send({
             status: 'success',
             room
        });
    });
 },
```

But I need to filter by language a property of the object (English or Spanish). I am looking in Mongoose documentation but I dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for other properties, then you have to use `Model.find`

```
Room.find({ _id: roomId, foo: 'bar' })
```

You can also use `Model.findOne` if you are querying for a single result

```
Room.findOne({ _id: roomId, foo: 'bar' })
```